# tkinter canvas rectange resize using item configure

Tags: tkinter

I have a canvas and have drawn a rectangle which I want to resize later based on changing data.

```
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 130, 80, 20)
```

For color, it looks like there is a "fill" property, but not sure how we can change the coordinates, particularly height.

```
canvas.itemconfigure(rect, fill="#000000", ...want to change height...)
```

Could you please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `canvas.coords(...)` to resize the rectangle:

```
def resize_rect(dy):
    # get the current geometry of rectangle
    coords = canvas.coords(rect)
    # update its height by modifying the last value of coords
    coords[-1] += dy
    # update the rectangle
    canvas.coords(rect, coords)
```